# ncdf missing Value

Tags: r

I try to read one ncdf file , 
in the header written that missing value is "Missval:1e+30" but in the data I see 9999 . 
I check with ncdump in linux , and it's fine. and missing value recognize by that. 
how can I tackle with such problem to get rid of missing values?

```
head(get.var.ncdf(nc,4))
```

[1] 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R uses the special symbol `NA` to code missing values.

If your data has 9999 to code missing values, then your metadata header is lying, and you will have to replace them manually. Generally, you would do something like:

```
 > x = c(1,2,3,9999,55,9999)
 > x[x==9999] <- NA
 > x
 [1] 1 2 3 NA 55 NA
```

Replacement for matrix objects is similar. And basic R stuff.

Its possible that you already have some NA values in your data, as well as the 9999 values. Check with `any(is.na(x))` - if TRUE, there's at least one NA in there (which probably came from the missing data value in the header).

Comment: Thanks, but I think this problem coming from ncdf Package.

Comment: Well, there's no way we can see the problem without seeing a data file with the problem in it.

Answer (score 0):

I find the Answer , the problem is coming from package "ncdf" but now I install "RNetCDF"

package and every thing working well.

```
head(var.get.nc(nc,5))
```

[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

but I find sometimes finding good package is tricky.